# mpromise/Monk promise never resolves

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, monk

I can't seem to figure out why my promise never resolves when I pass it a function. I have a class method like this:

```
test(){
    return this.dbCollection.insert(...);
}
```

Which is inserting some data into a MongoDB collection via Monk. It returns a promise. I'm calling this method from another class like this:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();
testClass.test().onResolve(...);
```

Here's where I'm hitting trouble. If I do this:

```
testClass.test().onResolve(console.log('Resolved!'));
```

The promise resolves, I see "Resolved!" in the console, and everything works as expected. If I check using the MongoDB console, I can see the data was indeed inserted. However, if I do this:

```
testClass.test().onResolve(function(err, data){
    console.log('Resolved!');
});
```

The promise never resolves, nothing is printed to the console, but the data is still inserted. Has anyone ever seen this behavior before? I believe it's an issue with mpromise, so I tagged Mongoose since it uses the same package for promises.

Comment: Well if you pass `undefined` and execute `console.log` immediately, that doesn't necessarily mean that the promise is actually resolved.

Comment: Have you tried adding an error handler? Btw, you should usually always use `then` and not some `onResolve` method.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the promise isn't necessarily resolved (I think that's the crux of the matter), but the behavior is the same using .onResolve() and .then(). The whole block is surrounded by an error handler, and unfortunately, it's not throwing any errors.

Comment: Not a try-catch statement I mean, but rather `.then(function(data) { console.log("fulfilled", data); }, function(err) { console.error("rejected", err); });`!

Comment: Ah, yes, I've already tried that too, and unfortunately the result is the same. EDIT: I just did it again as a sanity-check to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @Bergi. Like you suggested, the promise wasn't actually resolving. It turned out to be a problem with mpromise's `all()` method (i.e. apparently I don't fully understand how it works). `test()` was returning an aggregation of promises using `all()`, and that's what wasn't resolving. When that was taken out of the equation, everything worked as expected. Now to figure out what's going on with `all()`...